# Extend a System.Windows.Forms.Button and change default Text in c#

Tags: c#, button, text, controls, default

I have created a custom control button by extending the System.Windows.Forms.Button class.

I have set the default .Text .Width and .Height in the constructor of the new class.

When I drop this control onto a form, the IDE is smart enough to pay attention to the Width and Height specified in the constructor and assign these properties to the new button being created, but it ignores the Text property, and assignes the .Text of the button to be "ucButtonConsumables1"

Is there a way to set the .Text to a default value of my choosing?

```
public partial class ucButtonConsumables : System.Windows.Forms.Button {
    public ucButtonConsumables() {

        this.Text = "Consumables";                   
        this.Width = 184;
        this.Height = 23;

        this.Click += new EventHandler(ucButtonConsumables_Click);

    }

    void ucButtonConsumables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        MessageBox.Show("Button Clicked")

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you run the program and check if the Text is what you meant ? i feel you are checking this in the designer, shouldn't be the case when you would run it

Comment: You are trying to fight the custom designer for a button.  Winning this fight isn't easy, you are trying to do something *very* unusual.  It makes little sense to give *every* button the same Text.

Comment: Yes - i am definately fighting the designer. The designer assigns the control a name and wants to assign the .Text property to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Hide Text property from designer serialization:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public override string Text
{
    get { return base.Text; }
    set { base.Text = value; }
}
```

Or create designer with default values:

```
public class ConsumablesButtonDesigner : System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner
{
    public override void OnSetComponentDefaults()
    {
        base.OnSetComponentDefaults();
        Control.Text = "Consumables";
    }
}
```

And provide that designer to your button:

```
[Designer(typeof(ConsumablesButtonDesigner))]
public class ucButtonConsumables : Button
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: First option needs compilation to refresh button's default text.

Comment: The second method above works very nicely. The first method including clean rebuild etc. didn't work for me, but possibly would with persistance.

Comment: @timothy for first method to work you need to compile project. After compilation, default designer text will be replaced by yours

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not possible for doing it in the constructor. If you are sure that the value will not be changed again do it this way. Overriding the Text Property and returning the constant.

```
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "Consumables";
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to override the Text property in derived class to change.

```
public override string Text { get; set; }
```

Comment: On just overriding the property the value will not be set. When the control is loaded the Text property will be reset.